# Append in Python not in O(1)

Tags: python

I'm trying to monitor complexity in Python's lists. So I wrote the script above thinking I would have a O(1) complexity for inserting an item et the end and a O(n) complexity for an insertion in the beginning as [it is written here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

```
import time

for p in [3,4,5,6,7]:

    n = 10**p
    print("n =", n, ":")
    
    # Creation of a list [0, 1, ..., n]
    li = list(range(n))
    
    start = time.perf_counter()
    # Adding item at the end
    li.append('a')
    stop = time.perf_counter()
    duration = round((stop - start)*1000, 3)
    
    print("Time for insertion at the end :", duration, "ms")
    
    start = time.perf_counter()
    # Adding item at the beginning
    li.insert(0,'a')
    stop = time.perf_counter()
    duration = round((stop - start)*1000, 3)

    print("Time for insertion at the beginning :", duration, "ms")
    print()
```

And the result :

```
n = 1000 :
Time for insertion at the end : 0.001 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.001 ms

n = 10000 :
Time for insertion at the end : 0.003 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.007 ms

n = 100000 :
Time for insertion at the end : 0.036 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.098 ms

n = 1000000 :
Time for insertion at the end : 0.05 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 1.001 ms

n = 10000000 :
Time for insertion at the end : 0.257 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 11.453 ms
```

So, the insertion in the beginning is clearly O(n) but the insertion at the end is clearly not O(1).

Can anybody explain this to me ?

config: Python 3.8.5 on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

So, I tried with timeit (as suggested) and the results are as they should be.

at the beginning O(n):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("liste.insert(0,'a')",setup='liste = list(range(10**3))', number=1000)
0.0012012630177196115
>>> timeit.timeit("liste.insert(0,'a')",setup='liste = list(range(10**4))', number=1000)
0.008087130001513287
>>> timeit.timeit("liste.insert(0,'a')",setup='liste = list(range(10**5))', number=1000)
0.06115017700358294
>>> timeit.timeit("liste.insert(0,'a')",setup='liste = list(range(10**6))', number=1000)
1.0330771339940839
>>> timeit.timeit("liste.insert(0,'a')",setup='liste = list(range(10**7))', number=1000)
11.236097862012684
```

at the end O(1):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("liste.append('a')",setup='liste = list(range(10**3))', number=1000000)
0.05697788399993442
>>> timeit.timeit("liste.append('a')",setup='liste = list(range(10**4))', number=1000000)
0.05759519099956378
>>> timeit.timeit("liste.append('a')",setup='liste = list(range(10**5))', number=1000000)
0.05135001099552028
>>> timeit.timeit("liste.append('a')",setup='liste = list(range(10**6))', number=1000000)
0.0584335429884959
>>> timeit.timeit("liste.append('a')",setup='liste = list(range(10**7))', number=1000000)
0.04910806700354442
```

Since timeit execute the setup only once, it adds one element over and over in the same list.

So I tried this:

```
import time

for p in [3,4,5,6,7]:
    
        n = 10**p
        print("n =", n, ":")
        
        # Creation of a list [0, 1, ..., n]
        li = list(range(n))
        
        for j in range(3):
            start = time.perf_counter()
            # Adding item at the end
            li.append('a')
            stop = time.perf_counter()
            duration = round((stop - start)*1000, 3)
            
            print("Time for insertion at the end :", duration, "ms")
        

        for j in range(3):
            start = time.perf_counter()
            # Adding item at the beginning
            li.insert(0,'a')
            stop = time.perf_counter()
            duration = round((stop - start)*1000, 3)

            print("Time for insertion at the beginning :", duration, "ms")
        
        print()
```

and the results:

```
n = 1000 :
Time for insertion at the end : 0.004 ms
Time for insertion at the end : 0.0 ms
Time for insertion at the end : 0.0 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.001 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.001 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.001 ms

n = 10000 :
Time for insertion at the end : 0.002 ms
Time for insertion at the end : 0.0 ms
Time for insertion at the end : 0.0 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.007 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.006 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.006 ms

n = 100000 :
Time for insertion at the end : 0.042 ms
Time for insertion at the end : 0.001 ms
Time for insertion at the end : 0.001 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.113 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.099 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.087 ms

n = 1000000 :
Time for insertion at the end : 0.064 ms
Time for insertion at the end : 0.001 ms
Time for insertion at the end : 0.001 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 1.362 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 1.144 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 0.943 ms

n = 10000000 :
Time for insertion at the end : 0.336 ms
Time for insertion at the end : 0.002 ms
Time for insertion at the end : 0.001 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 15.727 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 15.441 ms
Time for insertion at the beginning : 13.837 ms
```

So it's just the "first access" to the list that takes some extra time. If I change the order, the extra time is on the insertion at the beginning.

Still, my curiosity isn't satisfied. Why is there this latency, that depends on the size of the list, in the first access? (sorry for the long post)

Comment: You use `insert` not `append`, read your link again, `insert` is O(n), 5th line of the table

Comment: ... and read the footnote [1]

Comment: Also I'd say you can't count the tie for 1 operation, that's so dependant of other thing, count the time of 1k, 1m and 1g consecutives insertions, then you can have an nice average time

Comment: @azro They used both append and insert.

Comment: Can you give us a few details, Python version, OS, specs? Because Running this code I get pretty clear O(1) behaviour for append.

Comment: I would suggest using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/timeit.html). Measuring an operation one time is not very representative.

Comment: @arzo 1) I use both insert and append. The point is to compare both.
2) also I just want the time for *one* insertion. By using many I could go into some sort of optimization by Python. I want to keep it simple.

Comment: @DeepSpace In fact I read the footnote, and it's not really helpfull since my list has no history.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon details added

Comment: @Wups I may try timeit. time.perf_counter() was just simpler. And every time I run the script the results are almost the same.

Comment: I get very O(1) for append.  Even moreso if I do 10 appends for each iteration.

Comment: `append` utilizes [table doubling](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~rademacher.10/Sp16_2331/datastructII.pdf) for **amortized** O(1) time. This means that many appends, averaged out, will be constant time, but a single append could be anywhere up to O(N) time if it has to reallocate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of lists in Python is dynamic. Not all appends have the same cost though, because of the way a dynamic list works.
Initially a fixed space is allocated to the list. When the allocated space is full and we want to append an element, a new space twice as big as the previous space is allocated to the list, and all the lists items are copied to the new location.
So if the allocated space is not full, it takes O(1) to append, but if the allocated space is full it takes O(n) (because we need to copy first).

The cost of appending n items (assuming initially two units of space are allocated):

```
  (1) + (1)    # costs of appending the first two items
+ (2+1) + (1)  # costs of appending the next two items
+ (4+1) + (1) + (1) + (1)  # costs of appending the next four items
+ (8+1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) # costs of appending the next eight items
+ (16+1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1)
+ (32+1) + ...
...
```

This equals `2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + n` which is roughly 2n. So n `append` operations cost in total 2n. So on average each costs `O(1)`. This is called amortized cost.